# Stuck in infinite loop. Any way to break vba into Code when Control+Break doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I have code stuck.
It might be in an infinite loop.
Not sure.

Is there a way to break the program to stop at the current line of code that it is running on?

I'd like to avoid shutting down excel because I want to be able to catch where in the loop it is, and by going into the code, I will be able to tell how much processing was done.  I would like to break into the code, if possible.

It is stuck on hour glass.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> doesn't seem to work

Seems like the running code has hijacked all the quota that cpu is giving to excel.

If there is nothing I can do now, is there something in the future I can do to where I can more easily break into the code?

I'm thinking that an intermittent wait within a loop might be a feasible solution.

Comment: Can you show *some* of that loop code? A simple [mcve] suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, include a `DoEvents` inside the loop. It will run a little slower, but you will be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to stop it from running.

Comment: ok, that seems to be good info.  I found this article which says that you should do a sleep before the doevents:  http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/examples/avoiddoevents.asp

Comment: You can do that, assuming you don't care about making the loop run even slower. It's up to you.

Comment: As `DoEvents` calls `sleep(0)` I don't see why you would call it. Also DoEvents is dangerous if not thought through as you must prevent that sub from being reentered while in `DoEvents`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163078/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-acatinlove).

Answer (score 1):

Create a progress dialog when entering the loop and include a `Cancel` button. Within your loop check for the `Cancel` signal/event. This also gives you some flexibility on how you react to the `Cancel` - you could stop the loop and display key information in a new dialog box (for example).

Basic steps to achieve what I have described (not necessarily the most elegant or the most re-useable, but simple enough for those of lesser experience):

- create a modeless (not modal) Form with either suitable labels or a progressbar item (for 
  visual effect). Include a public property (Boolean) for Cancel (e.g.
  `boolCancel`)
- Place a button on form and `onClick` set `boolCancel =    True`
- In your main code, show the form just before your problem loop.
  while in your loop you can update some label or progress bar on the
  form so that you have a visual indication of whether the loop is
  doing something of value or if it is now simply spinning its wheels. 
  How you do this depends on what your loop is doing.
- Also while in your loop check your `boolCancel` value. If true then
  display any    state information you want and break from the loop.
- If    your loop ends    normally, hide/unload the progress dialog.

Comment: You should probably mention that "show the form just before your problem loop" needs to show the form with `vbModeless`, because the default `vbModal` will show the form as a dialog, and the loop won't start until the dialog is closed.

Comment: Upvoting for the concept of displaying a progress indicator - which is a great idea for any long-running operation. I just don't agree with the proposed implementation, but the idea is good.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - as noted, not the most elegant, but simple enough to implement in a one-off situation. I have edited the answer to include modeless.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Interesting article and different from how I have set mine up. I currently have my events in a public `EventsHandler` but no reason why I can't declare them in my progress form. The general concept is the same with a different implementation, my main code opens the form, and the loops fire events when required (initiate progressbar, updateprogressbar, updatestatus). In terms of Cancel, I prefer a 'positive' cancel signal because so many users could click the little red 'x' accidentally.

Comment: That's just an implementation detail - the worker code gets to confirm cancellation anyway.